# Full width container bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm using Bootstrap v5 alpha to create a simple dashboard.

Bootstrap says that you must necessarily use `.container`, `.container-fluid` or some `.container-{size}` and then use `.row` and the `.col` columns. But I need the dashboard to have no side margins and there is no bootstrap container that has no margin.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no built-in Bootstrap container component that omits the margins it's easily achievable with utility classes.  The mechanism changes slightly in Bootstrap 5.x as it removes the `.no-gutters` class but all you really need to do is:

1. Remove the X-axis padding from your `.container`
2. Remove the X-axis padding from your `.row`

The former is achieved with `px-0` and the latter is achieved with either `.no-gutters` (Bootstrap 4.x) or `g-0` (Bootstrap 5.x)

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-danger px-0">
  <div class="row g-0 bg-info">
    <div class="col bg-success"><p>Column #1</p></div>
    <div class="col bg-primary"><p>Column #2</p></div>
    <div class="col bg-warning"><p>Column #3</p></div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In the above code sample you'll note that the container has the `bg-danger` class but we're not seeing any red background.  Nor are we seeing the `bg-info` color applied to the row.  That's because we've effectively removed the margins that Bootstrap's grid system defaults to!